# ActionCable starting on every rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I used a tiny bit of ActionCable on a previous project and now whenever I run `rails s` in a new project I get the following error:

```
Started GET "/cable" for ::1 at 2017-06-11 16:38:19 -0500
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT 
"schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for ::1 at 2017-06-11 16:38:19 -0500
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, 
HTTP_CONNECTION: Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
Subscription class not found: "ProductsChannel"
```

I'm not understanding why this seems to be carrying over from my last project into all my other projects.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like a client tries to connect to a `ProductsChannel` which is not actually present. Could you take a look into your action_cable folder in the app/ directory if the ProductsChannel is present?

Comment: There was on a previous project of mine. The strange part is now whenever I start a rails server for a different project, I'm still seeing that channel called. I've tried restarting server but keep getting this error

Comment: Probably the javascript still in the cache of your browser. Try to clear it.

Comment: Looks like that did it! Thank you!